# I added a second personal account to my employer encrypted MacBook Pro and now I'm running into permissions problems

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro for work. My employer encrypted the hard drive somehow (not sure of the process but I can look if you let me know where to look).

I added a second account to use for personal computing and it was working fine for a while. However, once I restarted the machine, I was able to log into my personal account again but I didn't have read access to my home directory. Which obviously breaks a bunch of stuff.

Here are some commands:

*Note: `admin` is my employer's admin account, `aaaaaaaaa` is the work account that was set up by my employers (not the real name), and `matt` is my personal account.*

```
# ls -al /Users
[... Shared, .localized, etc ...]
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 admin      staff        442 Nov 22 12:03 admin
drwxr-xr-x+ 85 aaaaaaaaa  1897370479  2890 Dec 23 17:01 aaaaaaaaa
drw-r--r--+ 50 matt       staff       1700 Dec  8 23:59 matt

# ls -al /Users/matt
ls: .: Permission denied
ls: ..: Permission denied
ls: .CFUserTextEncoding: Permission denied
ls: .DS_Store: Permission denied
ls: .Trash: Permission denied
ls: .bash_aliases: Permission denied
[... More of the same ...]

# whoami
matt
```

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the execution permission set on your home folder, so you can't `ls /Users/matt`. But you are still the owner of your home directory, so you can set permissions. Just do:

```
chmod u+x /Users/matt
```

This will set the execute bit on you home folder. You may need to set the execution permission for subfolders, too.

Comment: What would have changed this? I just rebooted.

Comment: I don't know... any user with root privileges could have done that. Also try to repair the permissions with Disk Utility.